# Is it possible for a Hungarian national to obtain a Chinese visa in The 'Stans / Central Asia?

Tags: visas, china, overland, central-asia, hungarian-citizens

I have a well-travelled Hungarian friend currently in Kyrgyzstan in his travels around Central Asia.

He says he can't go to Mongolia overland on this trip because he can't get a visa for China unless he goes back to Hungary.

Is this true or is there something he doesn't know?

Comment: Not an answer because I don't know the specific case of Kyrgyzstan, but, generally, outside of HK and Macao, obtaining a Chinese visa as a non-resident is impossible (or very hard at least). However, in, how should we say, countries with a good to excellent relationship with corruption and alternative solutions, there usually are travel agencies around the embassy/consulate who can arrange things. For a price.

Comment: @dda: I've obtained all of my Chinese visas except one in countries I was not a resident of. But I'm not Hungarian and I've not been to Central Asia.

Comment: And I have the exact experience to you (with 11 years in HK and 28 in Asia). But then again I'm French, and we are on China's shitlist...

Comment: Why on earth are you entering China if you are traveling overland from Kyrgyzstan to Mongolia? You could go via Kazakhstan (which is visa free if I recall correctly) and Russia instead. https://caravanistan.com/transport/bus-shared-taxi/kazakhstan/to-mongolia/

Comment: @chx. Well that friend's trip is over now but last time I met him on the road he was travelling by road and while Kyrgyzstan and Mongolia both have borders with China, Mongolia does not have a border with Kazakhstan. So why on earth and why in the air likely have different answers.

Answer (score 2):

The go-to resource for this type of question is [Caravanistan](https://caravanistan.com/visa/china/). Also check their forum for details.

While it seems that neither in Bishkek nor in Osh it is possible to obtain a Chinese visa at the moment, there seem to be other embassies in the area willing to hand out visa.

Also note their remark:

> Chinese embassies change their rules for foreigners monthly, sometimes
>   weekly, daily or even within the same day.